# iFrame is not displaying website (cross-site request error)

Tags: html, cors

I have been on an adventure to get a sportsbook dashboard in my mancave. With the main goal to display the lines of my Prefered sportsbook. Based on some googling and digging all the API's cost money. I settled on using the Game Center by Pregame, which I use quite often anyways.

So they have embed code for the GameCenter and I have a fairly basic HTML page going but somethings not quite right and it's displaying all wonky. I can't tell if it's my code or Pregame that is the issue. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Link to the Static Page: https://dashboard.megustasports.com/Untitled-1.html

Pregame Gamecenter: https://pregame.com/game-center

### EDIT

Here are the errors from the Chrome console

> Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by
> specifying its SameSite attribute Because a cookie's SameSite
> attribute was not set or is invalid, it defaults to SameSite=Lax,
> which prevents the cookie from being sent in a cross-site request.
> This behavior protects user data from accidentally leaking to third
> parties and cross-site request forgery.
>
> Resolve this issue by updating the attributes of the cookie: Specify
> SameSite=None and Secure if the cookie should be sent in cross-site
> requests. This enables third-party use. Specify SameSite=Strict or
> SameSite=Lax if the cookie should not be sent in cross-site requests
>
> 9 cookies Name    Domain & Path .te.dpr   pregame.com/
> _ga   .pregame.com/
> _gid  .pregame.com/ .te.w pregame.com/ Telligent.Evolution-UI pregame.com/ tzoffset   pregame.com/
> tzid  pregame.com/ .te.dpr    pregame.com/utility
> .te.w pregame.com/utility 2 requests pg.authentication.js
> error-notfound.aspx?item=%2fassets%2fscripts%2fpg.…entication&user=extranet%5cAnonymous&site=website

Here is the HTML I am currently using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Here the title</title>
    <style>
            *{
                margin: 0px;
            }
            iframe {
                display: block !important;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100vh;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

 
    <script src="https://pregame.com/assets/scripts/tear/tear.js" data-type="generic" data-url="https://pregame.com/game-center?ts_i=game-center"></script>




</body>
</html>
```

In theory, the end result should only contain the table from the page linked above and look something similar to this:
[image]

Comment: Your static page is no longer working, it looks pregame has blocked it by CORS policy. (If they providing an api, then you should be able to get it unblocked)

Comment: There is no html in your iframe static page...that's why it's not showing.

Comment: Your bounty is expiring a in a few hours. If my answer is sufficient consider accepting my answer and/or awarding a bounty, otherwise provide feedback or update your question so that I and others can attempt to answer your question adequately. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty and https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/09/23/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an iframe, try making a HTTP request and storing that in a div:

```js
var cors_api_url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';

function doCORSRequest(options, printResult) {
  var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
  x.open(options.method, cors_api_url + options.url);
  x.onload = x.onerror = function() {
    printResult(
      (x.responseText || '')
    );
  };
  if (/^POST/i.test(options.method)) {
    x.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  }
  x.send(options.data);
}

doCORSRequest({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://pregame.com/game-center/',
  data: ''
}, function printResult(result) {
  document.querySelector('.result').innerHTML = result;
});
```

```html
<div class="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

CORS is designed to prevent malicious websites from imitating a legitimate one. The Pregame Game Center’s CORS policy requires that the website embedding an iframe containing their website be on the same domain. To use an iframe from your domain, the Pregame Game Center developers would have to add your domain to their CORS policy.

## Solution

Consider instead programmatically navigating their website and pulling information you need from it (scraping), then creating your own website to display that information. This is the most roundabout way, but generally accepted if there is no API you can use to access the information you need.  Through investigation you may even come across a JSON formatted endpoint used by their front end to retrieve information to be displayed (their private API) that you can use.

## Note

Scraping and republishing information produced by Pregame Game Center may be against their terms and conditions. You may be able to avoid legal implications if you host the website locally, or remotely behind authentication.

## References

CORS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Web scraping (Python - Beautiful Soup) Tutorial: https://realpython.com/beautiful-soup-web-scraper-python

Django (Python web framework): https://www.djangoproject.com

Comment: I think you've misread the question and then updated it to fit your answer! See "somethings not quite right and it's displaying all wonky" - how can this be affected by CORS? Whilst the reproduceable has a CORS issue, its not the issue that's being asked. I assume the reproduceable has not been setup correctly (or temporally unavailable)

Comment: @Greg according to the existing CORS policy on Pregame Game Center, I’m not sure how the author could possibly get this working. Wonky == JavaScript executing but no content in iFrame, from what I understand, as JavaScript being used is just creating an Game Center Pregame iFrame.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use `iframe` to display some of the websites like `Google`.
This is a security measure implemented to protect their website and customer data from being attacked.

If you want to get some details of the website, you can use their `API` if they provide.

That is the best option.

You can search for a bunch of API's available on the web for your requirement.